# OAuth token Unauthorized on browser

Tags: java, angular, oauth-2.0, http-headers, angular7

I'm using Angular 7 and I got a problem with Headers.

This is my code:

```
    signin() {
    let signinData = this.signinForm.value;

    this.encoded = btoa("my-trusted-client:secret");

    let header = new Headers();

    header.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + this.encoded);

    header.append('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');

    this.http.post(this.url + '/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=' + signinData.username + '&password=' + signinData.password, { headers: header })
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
     })
    }
```

Output Error:

> error: "Unauthorized"
>
> message: "Unauthorized"
>
> path: "/barometre/oauth/token"
>
> status: 401
>
> timestamp: "2019-04-19T12:35:47.699+0000"

When I test it on Postman I got the results:
[image]

***Edit:***

The problem was on the request signature. I changed this:

```
this.http.post(this.url + '/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=' + signinData.username + '&password=' + signinData.password, { headers: header })
```

By This:

```
this.http.post(this.url + '/oauth/token', params, { headers: header })
```

with

> let params: URLSearchParams = this.serialize(this.data);

and generate new function

```
serialize(obj: any): URLSearchParams {
        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var element = obj[key];
                params.set(key, element);
            }
        }
        return params;
        console.log(params);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the request signature. I changed this:

```
this.http.post(this.url + '/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=' + signinData.username + '&password=' + signinData.password, { headers: header })
```

By This:

```
this.http.post(this.url + '/oauth/token', params, { headers: header })
```

with

> let params: URLSearchParams = this.serialize(this.data);

and generate new function

```
serialize(obj: any): URLSearchParams {
        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var element = obj[key];

                params.set(key, element);
            }
        }
    return params;
    console.log(params);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `HttpHeaders` in `post`. Check [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)

```
const header= {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.encoded
  })
};
```

Also make sure that your Authorization token is valid.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this is not the problem. It's was a problem with request signature.